# Joining a sql table rows with all other rows of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm beginner in SQL Server querying. I have assigned to a task where I need to self join a table.

[image]

Above is table structure. And I need result as below. I have tried using self join , sub query etc. I couldn't get result.

```
ReqStatusId ReqStatus ChildId  ChildReqStatus
1           Open      2        On Hold 
1           Open      3        Closed  
2           On Hold   1        Open       
2           On Hold   3        Closed  
3           Closed    1        Open       
3           Closed    2        On Hold
```

Result should come as: Each row in a table should joined with all other rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is achieved through a `cross join`. If you select the table twice you would get the desired result.

```
select a.reqstatusid, a.reqstatus, b.reqstatusid as childreqstatusid,
b.reqstatus as childreqstatus
from table a, table b
where a.reqstatusid <> b.reqstatusid
```

Answer (score 3):

use [*`CROSS JOIN`*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx), Which gives you the Cartesian product between two tables

```
Select * 
From YourTable A
CROSS JOIN YourTable B
Where A.ReqStatusId <> B.ReqStatusId
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `JOIN` on `ReqStatusId <> ReqStatusId`:

```
WITH Tbl(ReqStatusId, ReqStatus) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'Open' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'On Hold' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Closed'
)
SELECT
    t1.*,
    ChildId = t2.ReqStatusId,
    ChildReqStatus = t2.ReqStatus
FROM Tbl t1
INNER JOIN Tbl t2
    ON t2.ReqStatusId <> t1.ReqStatusId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.reqstatusid, a.reqstatus, b.reqstatusid,
b.reqstatus
from table a
inner join table b on A.ReqStatusId = B.ReqStatusId 
Where A.ReqStatusId <> B.ReqStatusId
```